# side by side cumulative barplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a problem when plotting some graphs.
I have 3 biological samples: October 2021, April 2022 and October 2022.
I was able to easily make cumulative barplots of my abundances from each sample. However I wonder if there is a line of code that allows in ggplot to be able to do cumulated and side by side barplots.

I have my codes to do it separately for each sampling:

```
b <- ggplot(densegroupOct22, aes(fill=group, y=density, x=station)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + xlab("Station") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle("Barplot of group density in october 21")
```

[Cumulative barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrxmw.png)

So for a bar plot side by side I can change the "position" in the geom_bar() :

```
b2 <- ggplot(densegroup, aes(fill=group, y=density, x=station)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + xlab("Station") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle("Barplot of group density")
```

[barplot side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsfUD.png)

but as I expected they are not cumulated like my first plot, since an argument is missing and I don't know how to tell him to put the cumulated barplots side by side according to the sampling dates

thanks for help !

Comment: Hi clemycg, is it possible to share a sample of the data from `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the plots side by side, facet by `Group` and remove the space between panels. Something like the following.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1_long, aes(Station, density, fill = embranchement)) +
  geom_col() +
  ylab(expression("Densité en" ~ m^2)) +
  ggtitle("Diagramme en bâton des densités des embranchements") +
  facet_wrap(~ Group) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df1 <- iris
names(df1)[5] <- "Group"
df1$Group <- c(rep("Octobre 2021", 50), rep("Avril 2022", 50), rep("Octobre 2022", 50))
df1$Group <- factor(df1$Group, levels = c("Octobre 2021", "Avril 2022", "Octobre 2022"))
df1_long <- df1 %>%
  mutate(across(-Group, ~.x + rexp(150, 1)), Station = "A") %>%
  bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(Station = "B")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Group, Station), names_to = "embranchement", values_to = "density")

head(df1_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Group        Station embranchement density
#>   <fct>        <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 Octobre 2021 A       Sepal.Length     5.96
#> 2 Octobre 2021 A       Sepal.Width     11.6 
#> 3 Octobre 2021 A       Petal.Length     1.82
#> 4 Octobre 2021 A       Petal.Width      1.27
#> 5 Octobre 2021 A       Sepal.Length     5.75
#> 6 Octobre 2021 A       Sepal.Width      3.59
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>